# I am trying to set default value in Billing_city in woocommerce but on checkout it says City field is required

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

**As I am serving only in one city, so that one City should be visible but not editable. I am using this code**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'my_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function my_woocommerce_checkout_fields($fields) {
  $fields['billing'] = my_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields['billing']);
  return $fields;
}

function my_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields) {
  // Note: Default value is only used if the user account does
  // not have any value for the meta field yet. (Empty value is
  // also a value.) Ensure that the value is set correctly.
  $fields['billing_city']['default'] = 'Karachi';
  $fields['billing_postcode']['default'] = '75500';

  // Disable the field in the form.
  // (Note: Does not prevent different values from being posted.)
  $fields['billing_city']['custom_attributes']['readonly'] = TRUE;
  $fields['billing_city']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
  $fields['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes']['readonly'] = TRUE;
  $fields['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;

  return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabled fields will not be submited, even if they have a value.

What you can do is connect to `woocommerce_checkout_posted_data` filter and check if the field doesn't exist, add the field with the value you wanted.

```
// manipulate the posted data
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'bt_manipulate_checkout_posted_data');
function bt_manipulate_checkout_posted_data ($data) {
    if (empty($data['billing_city'])) $data['billing_city']  = 'Karachi';

    return $data;
}
```

Add as many fields as needed

Comment: Yes, I have figured out that the field was disabled by the way thanks for the help, now it's working fine. It was only one line code which I had to comment